# Ограничить 301 редирект

Tags: .htaccess

Есть ссылка `site.com/page/2/`. Поставил на нее редирект на главную:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /page/(.*)/(.*) /
```

Но есть еще другие ссылки типа `site.com/news/page/2/`.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы редирект работал только на ссылки `site.com/page/2/` и не затрагивал ссылку `site.com/news/page/2/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае, видимо, не хватает признака начала строки `^`, с которого должно начинаться ваше выражение: `"^/page/(.*)/(.*)"`.
В целом, поскольку поиск жадный, то первая же группа `.*` съест всю строку до конца целиком. Вторая группа всегда будет пустой. Впрочем, поскольку результаты групп вы не используете, то выражение можно просто переписать как `"^/page/.*"` и все.

В целом то же самое действие будет выполнено (не уверен) и с использованием простого

```
 Redirect 301  "/page/" /
```

который проверяет совпадение начала URL.

Comment: Спасибо "^/page/.*" помогло.